# Unexpected Identifier

Tags: apex, javascript, onclick

Hi I am getting unexpected identifier error for below code. this a javascript added to a custom button on opportunity. Please help on the same

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )}     
var opptyId = "{!Opportunity.Id}";    
var connection = sforce.connection;    
integer soCount = [Select count() from csmso__Sales_Order__c WHERE csmso__Opportunity__c = opptyId && csmso__Status__c = 'Externally Approved' || 'Manual Approval'];     
if(soCount >1){ 
alert('Records limit exceeded'); 
}     
else{ 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("Order_PaymentSchedulerController ","createOrder",{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); 
alert(result); 
window.location.reload(); 
}
```

class:

```
global class Order_PaymentSchedulerController 
{
    webService static String createOrder(Id oppId) {
        Order__c orderRec = new Order__c();
        List<csmso__Sales_Order__c> salesOrders = [Select id,Name,csmso__Status__c from csmso__Sales_Order__c WHERE id =:oppId];
        orderRec.Name = salesOrders[0].Name;
        orderRec.Sales_Order__c = salesOrders[0].Id;
        insert orderRec;  
        return ('Successful : Order Created!');
    }     
}
```

[image]

Comment: integer soCount... this should be var type and your soql should be in sforce.connection.query

Comment: Changed. but still the same error

Comment: I do not believe that is how you declare and execute a query in button code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is modified code for you..

try this

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )}     
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var  soCount = result = sforce.connection.query("Select count() from csmso__Sales_Order__c WHERE csmso__Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND csmso__Status__c IN ('Externally Approved' , 'Manual Approval')");  
if(soCount >1){ 
alert('Records limit exceeded'); 
}     
else{ 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("Order_PaymentScheduler","createOrder",{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); 
alert(result); 
window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Comment: ratan i added your code bu i got error which I have attached

Comment: now it points out the same Malformed_Query error on 'Externally Approved' OR 'Manual Approval'

Comment: I have added the latest code with the linked controller class but its giving me an error which I have attaced

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43723/discussion-between-ratan-and-wizard).

Comment: Hi @ratan the sforce.connection.query is not working

Comment: @wizard could you please ask a new question with complete description

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136961/ault-codesfinvalid-query-filter-operator-error-onclick-button-javascript