# sf:INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR

Tags: javascript, custom-button, ajax-toolkit

This is my onclick javascript code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )}     
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
var soCount = sforce.connection.query("Select id, name, csmso__Status__c from csmso__Sales_Order__c WHERE csmso__Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}' AND csmso__Status__c IN ('Externally Approved','Manual Approval')"); 
var records = soCount.getArray("records"); 

var  recCount = sforce.connection.query("Select id,name,Opportunity__c from Order__c WHERE Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");
var recordssize = recCount.getArray("records");

alert(records.length); 
if(records.length>1) {
alert('There are more than 1 SO with approved status, please validate the Sales Orders!'); 
}
alert(recordssize.length); 
else if(recordssize.length>1){
alert('Payment already scheduled!');
}
else{ 
var result = sforce.apex.execute("Order_PaymentSchedulerController","updateOrder_Payment",{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"}); 
alert(result); 
window.location.reload(); 
}
```

> Error : unexpected token else

For reference `Salesorder` has a lookup field of `Opportunity` which is:
`Opportunity (csmso__Opportunity__c)`

Comment: You have to escape quotes in your code.

Comment: you mean Select count() from csmso__Sales_Order__c WHERE csmso__Opportunity__c = {!Opportunity.Id} AND csmso__Status__c IN ('Externally Approved' , 'Manual Approval')"

Comment: yes..something like this ..fieldName + ' = \'' + Externally Approved+ '\''

Comment: Its basically not checking the if(soCount >1) coz soCount is of type VAR so do you have any idea how can we typecast it

Comment: @wizard can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: @ratan i have added the code..changed the logic..now m getting Error : unexpected token else

Comment: @wizard just remove this `alert(recordssize.length); ` or move this inside if condition. it is breaking if else statement

Comment: got it just had to remove alert between the if else ladder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is just a `Javascript` issue. You cannot have any statements between `if`/`else` blocks. You have:

```
if(records.length>1) {
    alert(...); 
}
alert(recordssize.length); // PROBLEM
else if(recordssize.length>1) { ... }
```

Remove the intermediate `alert` and your error will go away.

**Note**: The **[JSLint](http://jslint.com/)** tool makes it much easier to hunt down these sorts of errors.

Comment: After digging through the comments, I realize that you actually had a separate issue at first. You should really ask a separate question in such case. The desired format here is **`Question`** and **`Answer`**, not question, many comments, and continuous edits.